# Devise sign_out can't find correct route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

Any idea why this isn't working?

This is odd, because testing locally it works fine. I sign out, it redirects through Devise's sign_out process to my homepage. But on Heroku I get a page missing error.

The Heroku logs are a bit baffling:

```
    2013-06-21T08:05:17.173706+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 115.87.109.249 at 2013-06-21 08:05:17 +0000
2013-06-21T08:05:17.173706+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-21T0
8:05:17.176805+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176805+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176805+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176805+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176805+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__434936903609672590__call__3559819517956854473__callbacks'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176805+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177608+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177608+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177608+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177608+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176805+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176805+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177608+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.176966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.178109+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.178109+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.178109+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177608+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177608+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177608+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177608+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177608+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.178109+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.178109+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.178109+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.178109+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.178109+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.177775+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.178109+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-06-21T08:05:17.178109+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
```

Comment: the error message is missing, so how can we help?

Comment: there is no error message, that's the problem. All I have is this log and Heroku's "We're sorry, something went wrong" but I can't recreate the problem on my localhost at all, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow this wiki page
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-sign_up-links-to-your-layout-template

Comment: Thanks @michael-szyndel. also @nikhil-d I am already using `:method => :delete` for signout and the Devise initializer is also set to use `:delete` so I don't understand why Heroku is using `:get`

Comment: Rails runs this delete requests with Javascript. JS error somethere in application.js? JS disabled?

Comment: Different staging config might be the case. Could you check for js errors please?

Comment: Thanks for the above link from @michael-szyndel, I fixed the issue by letting Devise use `:get` to sign users  out (by deleting `:method => :delete` from the sign-out code in my views.

Answer (score 1):

I have found, you are trying to call /users/sign_out with GET method

```
2013-06-21T08:05:17.173706+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 115.87.109.249 at 2013-06-21 08:05:17 +0000
```

while devise create route for DELETE method .. have you created route for it?

Comment: As far as I am aware, the routing is automatic when using the Devise gem. However, I did customize their registrations, for which I added the routing **devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}**